Why do I get clipping after weight transfer?
I'm trying to animate my character with clothes as separate objects. I transferred weights from the character mesh to the clothes (by name), but I'm still getting some clipping when I start posing the character.
Below is a screenshot with the character's arm rotated. As you can see, the shirt object is clipping through the jacket object. Can anyone help me figure out what the issue is?


You can use the Mask modifier to hide these faces (assign these vertices to a vertex group, select the vertex group in the Mask modifier and invert the selection).
